# Error in Returning in a Method

Tags: java

I have a very simple question about the following toString() method that I have created below. If words is an arrayList with the contents of {apple, banana, grape}, I was just wonderning if the method:

```
public String toString()
{
    for (int d = 0; d < words.size(); d++)
    {
        return "The word: " + words.get(d);
    }
    return "";
}
```

would return:

```
The word: apple
The word: banana
The word: grape
```

The reason that I ask this question is because when I ommited the line:

```
return "";
```

I got an error that said missing return statement, so I figured the computer might not be recognizing the return statement:

```
"return "The word: " + words.get(d);"
```

and instead of returning:

```
The word: apple
The word: banana
The word: grape
```

It would return:

```
null or ""
```

I am not sure if this is necessary, but I have also just put in the code that I had before I got the error missing return statement.

```
public String toString()
{
    for (int d = 0; d < words.size(); d++)
    {
        return "The word: " + words.get(d);
    }
}
```

The exact error was a red line that circled the second to last closed bracket. The exact error message was: "missing a return statement"

**Update 1:**

I really appreciate all the help and constructive criticism of the code that I can get. I hope I didn't turn this simple question into one too complex. Thank you very much :)

**Update 2:**

I am sorry for leaving so many notes. However, I was only just wondering if this is a common question that any of you guys see a lot because it seems like this comes up a lot in class, and the teacher assisstant can't answer the question. Thanks again :)

Comment: Your method doesn't seem to make sense, because it can't figure out _which_ fruit it should be printing, hence it is iterating over all of them.  As for the error, the compiler has detected that if the `for` loop should not execute, then there must be a return statement after that loop.  When you removed `return ""`, you broke the code.

Comment: Why are you putting a `return` statement inside a loop?  That means that the first time you go through the loop, you return from the method and you never go through the rest of the loop.  A method that returns a value returns just one value; how did you think the method was going to return three different values?

Comment: To answer your last questions: (1) I've seen several other posts here where questioners wrote a loop with a "return" statement like this and didn't understand why it was wrong.  (2) Anyone who can't answer this question shouldn't be a teaching assistant--at least in a computer science class.  (It's OK with me if they're an English Lit TA.)

Comment: @ajb I thought that the method would run through the entire loop each time returning a value for the method.

Comment: @ajb I know. The teacher assisstant isn't very good at his job. But, the proffessor is a genius and very smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only return one `String` from your method, not the individual `String`(s) you are currently trying to construct. Instead, use something like a `StringBuilder` to build your entire output and `return` once.

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int d = 0; d < words.size(); d++) {
        sb.append("The word: ").append(words.get(d)) //
                .append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Or the less efficient (but still `StringBuilder`, just many temporary and invisible ones)

```
public String toString() {
    String sb = "";
    for (int d = 0; d < words.size(); d++) {
        sb += "The word: " + words.get(d) + System.lineSeparator();
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very good answer; however we didn't learn StringBuilder yet.

Comment: Is there a different way I could do it where I only return it once.

Comment: @SteveDav You're not clear on what you want your method to return.  You can only return one `String`.  What do you want that `String` to be?

Comment: That is what I was originally thinking of doing. However, we also didn't learn lineSeperator.

Comment: Change it to `"\r\n"` on windows, and `"\n"` on everything else.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Just to clarify, you would do:

Comment: public String toString() {
    String sb = "";
    for (int d = 0; d < words.size(); d++) {
        sb += "The word: " + words.get(d) + "\n"
    }
    return sb;
}

Comment: I think a pertinent point is that **all paths in a function must return a value**. The reason the original code didn't work when you removed the final `return ""` line is because the loop isn't guaranteed to execute at all, and if that happened, nothing would be returned. If `words.size()` is equal to `0` (i.e. the string is empty) then the loop is skipped completely. You can have as many `return` statements as you want, as long as every path in the function hits one. Personally, I think it's nice to have a single return statement for clarity.